# Can a Personal Access Token with empty scope be used maliciously?

Tags: github

So I wish to use an Emacs plugin called [`grip-mode`](https://github.com/seagle0128/grip-mode), which uses an application called [`grip`](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) under the hood that uses GitHub’s API to render markdown text. But unless an access token (which can have an empty scope) is provided, it hits GitHub’s hourly rate limits. So I want to put an empty-scoped access token for grip-mode. Problem is, my Emacs configuration is stored in a public repository, and so, I want to make sure an access token with an empty scope can’t be used maliciously before I put it in my configuration. So, can an empty-scoped access token be used maliciously? Or is it harmless to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but at least one can use the PAT to consume your API limits, either by using the plugin normally or using the token maliciously.

From [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting):

> Authenticated requests are associated with the authenticated user, regardless of whether Basic Authentication or an OAuth token was used.

For example they can scrape PATs exposed on GitHub and use the tokens to perform high-rate API calls.

Or if one of your user use the token frequently, all other users will not be able to use the plugin.

Also, [GitHub does not recommend using your PAT in this case](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/about-apps#personal-access-tokens)

Comment: So then, what if I source the Token from a separate file that's not public. Would it be safe then? Or is it still a bad idea to use a token for it?

Comment: @Famiu Store PAT locally will be fine. In fact almost every token has to be saved somewhere locally. I don't think it is a bad idea.

Comment: Ah alright then, I'll accept your answer now